# Google Books API - How do I separate Book from Book Edition?

Tags: python, google-api

I'm using **Google Book Search API** to add missings bits and pieces to my database.

Problem is that The API gives me back a list of book editions, and not **reference to the original book** itself.

The data I'm trying to get is this:

> Original title: **The Hobbit**
>
> Original year of publication: **1937**

Can anyone help?

---

Just in case anyone asks: I'm developing this in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this snippet:

```
entry = self.service.get_by_google_id("XV0NAQAAIAAJ")
print entry.dc_title[0].text
print entry.date.text
```

Result is:
**The hobbit

1937**